# Google Map markers set from a postcode attr within individual divs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

so I have a google map that needs multiple locations / markers.
So far I have them just set in an array like this

```
var locations = [
    ['Sheffield', 53.381690, -0.277405, 3],
    ['Barnsley', 53.824976, -0.832214, 2],
    ['Leeds', 53.865486, -1.216736, 1]
];
```

What I need to do is pull them from individual attr tags from a div with the map code would look like this.

```
<div id="map">
    <div class="marker" postcode="S71 1ET" data-lat="53.381690" data-lng="-0.277405"></div>
    <div class="marker" postcode="M16 0RA" data-lat="53.824976" data-lng="-0.832214"></div>
    <div class="marker" postcode="S2 4SU" data-lat="53.865486" data-lng="-1.216736"></div>
</div>
```

Ideally also I'd like the locations to be populated via a postcode attr instead off the lat lng. So it would need to use Geocode?

Any help would be good all my code so far is below.

```
<div id="map">
            <div class="marker" postcode="S71 1ET" data-lat="53.381690" data-lng="-0.277405"></div>
            <div class="marker" postcode="M16 0RA" data-lat="53.824976" data-lng="-0.832214"></div>
            <div class="marker" postcode="S2 4SU" data-lat="53.865486" data-lng="-1.216736"></div>
        </div>

        <script>

        var locations = [
            ['Sheffield', 53.381690, -0.277405, 3],
            ['Barnsley', 53.824976, -0.832214, 2],
            ['Leeds', 53.865486, -1.216736, 1]
        ];

        function initMap() {

            var myLatLng = {lat: 53.774689, lng: 5.888672};

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                 zoom: 6,
                 center: myLatLng
            });

            var count;

            for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]),
                    map: map,
                    title: locations[count][0]
                });
            }

        }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally also I'd like the locations to be populated via a postcode attr instead off the lat lng

I tend to disagree.  If you have the lat and lng, use them.  Else indeed you need geocoding, address searching, ... which slows everything down, which is more code, which is waching out for people in different countries who might get a same postal code of a different country...

Anyway, this works:

```
<style>#map {height: 400px;}</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="markers">
  <div class="marker" data-postcode="S71 1ET" data-lat="53.381690" data-lng="-0.277405"></div>
  <div class="marker" data-postcode="M16 0RA" data-lat="53.824976" data-lng="-0.832214"></div>
  <div class="marker" data-postcode="S2 4SU" data-lat="53.865486" data-lng="-1.216736"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<script>
    // notice, jQuery makes it easier to read/write from/to HTML elements.  But it's not required.
    function readMarkersData() {
      var locations = [];
      var markerdivs = document.getElementById('markers').children;
      for(var i=0; i<markerdivs.length; i++) {
        var item = markerdivs[i];
        locations.push([
          item.getAttribute('data-postcode'),
          item.getAttribute('data-lat'),
          item.getAttribute('data-lng')
        ])
      }
      return locations;
    }
    function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: 53.774689, lng: 5.888672};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             zoom: 6,
             center: myLatLng
        });
        var count;
        var locations = readMarkersData();
        for (count = 0; count < locations.length; count++) {
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[count][1], locations[count][2]),
                map: map,
                title: locations[count][0]
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks i'll give this ago. I kind of worked it out but this looks cleaner so will utilise this. PS. The reason for postcode is just more user friendly for client use.